# Node.js Express mssql - How to pass back data fetched from DB via promise chain

Tags: sql-server, node.js, promise

I am new to MEAN environment and not an expert in using promises. I am confused how to achieve this behaviour using promise.
my router method makes call to service method which has promise chained to qyery DB and returns results. I want to send back those results to router so I can send to front end. Thats there problem lies and I get undefined.
Router.js:

```
myrouter('/api/getDatafromDB',(req,res){
results =getSQLResults();
res.send(results); //want to achieve that.

}

SQLServiceFile.js :

//Db connection code defined in separate js file - dbConfig.js and 
//imported in connection object

getSQLResults=function(){
connection.connect().then(    //promise1
function(recordset){
request.query('select * from xyz')  //promise 2
.then(
//recordset fetched fine here and want to pass to router.

rec= recordset['recordset']; //basically want to pass back rec.
console.log(rec);
connection.close();
).catch(function(err){
//error handling}
connection.close();)
}


).catch(//error handling code);

}
```

I tried different variations but did not work. Now I think somewhere I read that I need to pass back callback again in promise or something like that. I don't know. But I think If I change my code to use callbacks and not promise, it would work Or If I put back sql query code in router. 
I want to keep code structured like this so please suggest right method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is syntactically wrong. Maybe the below piece of code will help you, it's the right way to use promises and async programming. The pattern used below is known as `.then chaining`. We can chain multiple `.then` to achieve a synchronous pattern in js.

`.then` and `.catch` only accept a function as an argument.

```
myrouter('/api/getDatafromDB', (req,res) => {
  getSQLResults()
  .then( result => res.send(results) )
  .catch( err => ErrorHandler(err) )
}

SQLServiceFile.js :

//Db connection code defined in separate js file - dbConfig.js and 
//imported in connection object

function getSQLResults() {
  return connection.connect()
  .then( function() { 
    return request.query('select * from xyz') 
  })
  .then( function(recordset) {
    connection.close();
    return recordset['recordset'];
  })
  .catch( function(err) {
    connection.close();
    throw err; // it can be done so that you can handle the errors in myRouter
  });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to return a promise from `getSQLResults()`.

Comment: Also rethrow the error from the `catch()`, so it can be handled appropriately in `myrouter()`

Comment: about that, as we don't know how OP is handling the errors, I think it's best to leave it upon him. We can either rethrow or like what I do, pass it to the ErrorHandler so that it can be converted into a proper custom response and sent to the user; stopping all of the further processing. Anyways Updated the answers. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: Thanks all. i was able to fix the issue by make the method return the promise and handling that promise in router code.

Comment: @user3665943, If this answer, solves your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Accepted. Thanks